# De-structuring Mouse Move event in ReasonReact

Tags: reason, reason-react

Currently trying to pull `clientX` off a mouse move event in Reason React.  Here is the component currently:

```rust
type state = {
  count: int,
  hover: bool,
  mouseX: int,
  mouseY: int,
};

type action =
  | Hover
  | MouseMove(ReactEventRe.Mouse.t);

let component = ReasonReact.reducerComponent("EventTracking");

let make = _children => {
  ...component,

  initialState: () => { count: 0, hover: false, mouseX: 0, mouseY: 0 },

  reducer: (action, state) =>
      switch (action) {
      | Hover => ReasonReact.Update({ ...state, hover: !state.hover })
      | MouseMove(event) => ReasonReact.Update({ ...state, mouseX: state.mouseX + 1})
      },

    render: self =>{
      let hoverString = "Hover State => " ++ string_of_bool(self.state.hover);


      <div className="statistics" onMouseEnter={_event => self.send(Hover)} onMouseLeave={_event => self.send(Hover)} onMouseMove={event => self.send(MouseMove(event))}>
        <p>
          (ReasonReact.stringToElement(hoverString))
        </p>
        <p>
          (ReasonReact.stringToElement(string_of_int(self.state.mouseX)))
        </p>
      </div> 
    },
};
```

The code I'm assuming I need to change is in my reducer's `MouseMove` action, `mouseX` needs to be updated to `clientX` but I can't seem to pull it off the event object without throwing errors.

Any advice would be great, I also have no idea if using these synthetic events is the right approach to tracking mouse position in ReasonReact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be getting confused because `ReactEventRe.Mouse.t` is not a record or JS object type, but an abstract type which you manipulate with the functions in `ReactEventRe.Mouse`. It's pretty simple to translate though. To access the `clientX` property you use the `clientX` function. Fully qualified it would look like:

```
ReactEventRe.Mouse.clientX(event)
```

PS: You seem to be using an outdated version of ReasonReact. `ReactEventRe` has been replaced by `ReactEvent` and `ReactReact.stringToElement` with `ReasonReact.string` for example.

Comment: Oh gotcha, thank you.  And interesting on the Reason version.  I was just using Codesandbox's Reason template, so I guess that is out of date!